# Mono Android cross platform applications

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, monodevelop

I'am new to Mono and currently working on Mono for Android. I want to re-use the core or services layer so I created a separate project for services layer so I can use it later for iPhone and Windows mobile apps. In the services project there are some references to the web services which are call for various transactions.

When I try to call the the web service by referencing the services project from a Mono Android  application I revived "System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type xxxx" exception.

The web services  and the service project are working fine when tried it with a simple windows app.

Is there any way to achieve this.

I tried to link classes as mentioned in following article .

http://docs.xamarin.com/Android/Guides/Application_Fundamentals/Building_Cross_Platform_Applications/Sharing_Code_Options

Bit I found that web service referenced and resource file references, etc are not referring when you link a class. Example if I link a class in project B from Project A, if the class has web service calls and referenced resource files, once you linked to project A you'll get build errors. Saying the web services and  resource files are can not be found. I linked the resource files as well. But still I revived the same errors.

Any help on these issues are greatly appropriated. Thanks.

Comment: So you created a separate MonoDroid class library and linked the files from the services project?

Can you actually put the type errors where you've put "xxxx" in your exception above? This will tell us which libraries you're trying to use incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are any good at French... then the sample at http://www.e-naxos.com/Blog/post/Strategie-de-developpement-Cross-Platform-Partie-2.aspx (and http://www.e-naxos.com/Blog/post/Strategie-de-developpement-Cross-Platform-Partie-3.aspx) has some good information on sharing web service references between windows, windowsphone and monodroid

The key thing the author does is to import the web references separately for the two different paltforms - and to then use one `#if` to separate the different code.

I did start translating it... https://docs.google.com/document/d/1UQsy80qmXkVO7BRUb3f3vUxO2uQz9af1_PIQykAGzJA/edit - but pigeon English at best I'm afraid!